# Enabled JavaScript Message

Tags: javascript, php

how to print a message at opening of the site that "please enable JavaScript in your browser" ? and if msg is disabled than this msg should be print

Answer (score 4):

You can put this on your page:

```
<noscript><p>Please enable Javascript in your browser</p></noscript>
```

And, it will display only if javascript is disabled.

See [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/noscript) for reference.